# Is this normal for gcp Cloud SQL disk usage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I created a cloud sql db for learning purposes a while ago and have basically never used it for anything. Yet the storage / disk space keeps climbing:

**updated image**
Updating image to show timescale... this climb seems to be within just a few hours!

[image]
Is this normal? If not, how do I troubleshoot / prevent this steady climb? The only operations against the db seem to be backup operations. I'm not doing any ops (afaik).

Comment: I don't really know the timescale from that graph, but could it be log files? What's the rate-of-growth?

Comment: @Hitobat I just updated the image. It seems to be happening in matter of hours? Unless I'm reading the chart wrong??

Comment: Ok, now that I see the times the disk growth is only about 1.2MB/hour which to me feels tiny. So it feels like log messages or something similar. These logs should rollover after some time and free up space, I don't know how long though.

You can either leave it running for longer and see if the graph flattens, or email Google and ask what the configs for these are.

Comment: @hitobat I feel really stupid now - your answer makes perfect sense. I didn't pay attention to the vertical scale I just saw the slope and panicked, lol. Thanks!